# music library will not import; using Python 3.6 on a Windows 7 machine

Tags: python-3.x

Successful installation of the music library, but cannot `import music` or `from music import *`:

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#37>", line 1, in <module>
    from music import *
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\music\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .synths import *
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\music\synths.py", line 5, in <module>
    BT=BasicTables()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\music\tables.py", line 10, in __init__
    self.makeTables(size)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\music\tables.py", line 14, in makeTables
    self.square=n.hstack( ( n.ones(size/2)*-1 , n.ones(size/2) )  )
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 192, in ones
    a = empty(shape, dtype, order)
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: installed Jython, but still no changes :(

Comment: I can run python code within the Jython Environment for music, but still, cannot run anything within python IDLE shell

Comment: Looks like old `2.7` code, as `size/2` would stay an integer before `3.x` but now returns a float, which `numpy.ones()` doesn't allow.  If you feel like fiddling with source code you could change it to `size//2` but that's probably a rabbit hole you don't want to go down.